# Unable to create related model within forloop

Tags: django

I'm attempting to create a related model within a forloop, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot assign "False": "GoogleProfile.userprofile" must be a "UserProfile" instance.
```

Any thoughts as to how to get this working? my code is below

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    
    _, created = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(
                                            busname=column[0], 
                                            )
           
    google_profile = GoogleProfile.objects.create(
                                                userprofile=created,
                                                longitude=column[1],    
                                                latitude=column[2],    
                                                )
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`created` will be assigned `True` or `False` depending on whether the value was created or not. But here we are interested in the updated/created object itself:

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    userprofile, __ = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(
        busname=column[0]
    )
           
    google_profile = GoogleProfile.objects.create(
        userprofile=userprofile,
        longitude=column[1],
        latitude=column[2]
    )
```

You however likely do not need [**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) since you do not update any values, but [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    userprofile, __ = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
        busname=column[0]
    )
           
    google_profile = GoogleProfile.objects.create(
        userprofile=userprofile,
        longitude=column[1],
        latitude=column[2]
    )
```